# AngularJS submit button active when all input have a data

Tags: angularjs, validation, submit, form-submit, bootstrapvalidator

I have form with input fields, radio buttons, select boxes. Need submit button make active after when all fields have a data.
example my fields and button.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.birth.$touched && myForm.birth.$invalid }">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{getWord('Dob')}}<sup>*</sup></label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="1988-12-12" class="form-control" name="birth"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="patient.DOB"
                   data-placeholder=""
                   is-open="isOpened" datepicker-options="dpOptions"
                   close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" required/>

            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        ng-click="openCalender()"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </button>
            </span>

        <p ng-show="myForm.birth.$error.required" style="color:red" ng-if="myForm.birth.$touched">Date of birth is
            required.</p>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and code button

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-labeled btn-success" type="button" ng-click="makeAptmn()">
            <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>

            {{getWord('makebutton')}}
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger" type="button">
            <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>

            {{getWord('clearbutton')}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and need same for clear button, clear all input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your button code as:

```
<button class="btn btn-labeled btn-success" type="button" ng-click="makeAptmn()"
     ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
      <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>

      {{getWord('makebutton')}}
</button>
```

I added `ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"` which will disable the button when the any of the input field is not valid.

Comment: What do you want to do with the clean button.

Comment: You can use the `type="reset"` in your clear button. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: Glad this worked! @mark take a look at this library https://github.com/sagrawal14/bootstrap-angular-validation. I've make the library generic which works great for Angular + Bootstrap and removes all custom message code.

Comment: See customizations & demos here http://sagrawal14.github.io/bootstrap-angular-validation/#/customization-and-examples

Comment: I know, but need use together vith angular validation too. customers who use this form sometimes dont know why imput have a red border, but when have a message and easy to undarstand

Comment: Yes, that library is what all about of auto showing customizable messages automatically at different events of form. Well, feel free to explore when you get time.

Comment: You no longer have to write `<p ng-show="myForm.birth.$error.required" style="color:red" ng-if="myForm.birth.$touched">Date of birth is
            required.</p>

        </p>` like code.

Comment: next project im add your library, this project have allready just one form and 10 fields. so no problem, when have a free time can clean code and write all good.

Comment: Oh yes yes! Feel free to use anytime. I'm not forcing neither I'm promoting that library :D

Comment: you can make same library for angular2 and type script?

Comment: Yes, I've started migrating the same.